# Getting exception on PostUrlBuilder when build post URL for Volley Custom post request with array parameter with normal param

Tags: java, android, android-volley, urlencode, stringbuilder

I am trying to build a post URL for Volley custom request to post some data to server using post method with normal param and array param. But I get some exception when build the post url for request. I am getting exception before make a request with volley custom request.

```
     Map<String, String> params = new HashMap<>();
            params.put(API.Parameter.ANDROID_DEVICE_ID, appManager.getDeviceId());
            params.put(API.Parameter.ANDROID_APP_VERSION, appManager.getAppVersion());
            params.put("trip_no", MainActivity.temp_trip_id);

     Map<String, List<String>> arrayParams = new HashMap<>();
            arrayParams.put("ticket_id",ticket_id);
            arrayParams.put("ticket_name",ticket_name);
            arrayParams.put("ticket_price_each",ticket_price_each);

     PostUrlBuilder urlBuilder = new PostUrlBuilder(API.BOOK_TRIP_API_URL, params, arrayParams);
            String Url = urlBuilder.getQueryUrl();

            ObjectRequest<OnlineUserData> onlineUserDataObjectRequest = new ObjectRequest<OnlineUserData>(Request.Method.POST, Url, null,
                    new Response.Listener<OnlineUserData>() {
                        @Override
                        public void onResponse(OnlineUserData response) {

                        }
                    }, new Response.ErrorListener() {
                @Override
                public void onErrorResponse(VolleyError error) {

                }
            }, OnlineUserData.class);
            AppController.getInstance().addToRequestQueue(onlineUserDataObjectRequest);
```

My PostUrlBuilder.java class is:

```
public class PostUrlBuilder {
    private static final String TAG = PostUrlBuilder.class.getSimpleName();
    private String url;
    private Map<String, String> parameters;
    private Map<String, List<String>> arrayParameters;

    private String queryUrl;

    public PostUrlBuilder() {

    }

    public PostUrlBuilder(String url, Map<String, String> parameters, Map<String, List<String>> arrayParameters) {
        this.url = url;
        this.parameters = parameters;
        this.arrayParameters = arrayParameters;
        buildQueryUrl();
    }

    public PostUrlBuilder(Map<String, String> parameters, String url) {
        this.parameters = parameters;
        this.url = url;
    }

    private void buildQueryUrl() {
        StringBuilder urlBuilder = new StringBuilder(url);

        if (parameters != null && parameters.size() != 0) {
            urlBuilder.append("?");
            int i = 0;
            for (String key : parameters.keySet()) {
                String value = parameters.get(key);
                Log.d(TAG, "key= " + key + " & " + "value=" + value);
                try {
                    urlBuilder.append(String.format("%s=%s", key, URLEncoder.encode(value, "UTf-8")));
                } catch (UnsupportedEncodingException e) {
                    e.printStackTrace();
                }
                i++;
                if (i != parameters.size()) {
                    urlBuilder.append("&");
                }
            }
        }
        if (arrayParameters != null && arrayParameters.size() != 0) {
            if (parameters != null && parameters.size() != 0) {
                urlBuilder.append("&");
            } else {
                urlBuilder.append("?");
            }
            int i = 0;
            for (String key : arrayParameters.keySet()) {
                List<String> values = arrayParameters.get(key);
                int j = 0;
                for (String value : values) {
                    Log.d(TAG, "size = " + values.size() + " j = " + j + " key= " + key + " & " + "value=" + value);
                    try {
                        urlBuilder.append(String.format("%s[]=%s", key, URLEncoder.encode(value, "UTf-8")));
                        j++;
                        if (j != values.size()) {
                            urlBuilder.append("&");
                        }
                    } catch (UnsupportedEncodingException e) {
                        e.printStackTrace();
                    }
                }
                i++;
                if (i != arrayParameters.size()) {
                    urlBuilder.append("&");
                }
            }
        }
        queryUrl = urlBuilder.toString();
    }

    public String getUrl() {

        return url;
    }

    public void setUrl(String url) {
        this.url = url;
    }

    public Map<String, String> getParameters() {
        return parameters;
    }

    public void setParameters(Map<String, String> parameters) {
        this.parameters = parameters;
    }

    public String getQueryUrl() {
        return queryUrl;
    }

    public void setQueryUrl(String queryUrl) {
        this.queryUrl = queryUrl;
    }

    public Map<String, List<String>> getArrayParameters() {
        return arrayParameters;
    }

    public void setArrayParameters(Map<String, List<String>> arrayParameters) {
        this.arrayParameters = arrayParameters;
    }

    @Override
    public boolean equals(Object o) {
        if (this == o) return true;
        if (!(o instanceof PostUrlBuilder)) return false;

        PostUrlBuilder that = (PostUrlBuilder) o;

        return this.getUrl().equals(that.getUrl())
                && this.getParameters().equals(that.getParameters())
                && this.getArrayParameters().equals(that.getArrayParameters())
                && this.getQueryUrl().equals(that.getQueryUrl());
    }

    @Override
    public int hashCode() {
        int result = getUrl().hashCode();
        result = 31 * result + getParameters().hashCode();
        result = 31 * result + getArrayParameters().hashCode();
        result = 31 * result + getQueryUrl().hashCode();
        return result;
    }

    @Override
    public String toString() {
        return "GetUrlBuilder{" +
                "url='" + url + '\'' +
                ", parameters=" + parameters +
                ", queryUrl='" + queryUrl + '\'' +
                '}';
    }
}
```

I am getting exception in line below:

```
urlBuilder.append(String.format("%s[]=%s", key, URLEncoder.encode(value, "UTf-8")));
```

Error Log-cat shows errors below :

```
FATAL EXCEPTION: main
Process: com.shohoz.launch.cabin, PID: 12230
java.lang.NullPointerException
    at libcore.net.UriCodec.encode(UriCodec.java:132)
    at java.net.URLEncoder.encode(URLEncoder.java:57)
    at com.shohoz.launch.cabin.toolbox.PostUrlBuilder.buildQueryUrl(PostUrlBuilder.java:70)
    at com.shohoz.launch.cabin.toolbox.PostUrlBuilder.<init>(PostUrlBuilder.java:29)
    at com.shohoz.launch.cabin.fragment.RightFullSeatLayoutFragment.onlineCreateAndInsertIntoConfirm(RightFullSeatLayoutFragment.java:1105)
    at com.shohoz.launch.cabin.fragment.RightFullSeatLayoutFragment$15.onClick(RightFullSeatLayoutFragment.java:857)
    at android.support.v7.app.AlertController$ButtonHandler.handleMessage(AlertController.java:157)
    at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:102)
    at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:136)
    at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:5398)
    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invokeNative(Native Method)
    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:515)
    at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:864)
    at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:680)
    at dalvik.system.NativeStart.main(Native Method)
```

Thanks in advance.

**I've Figured out `arrayParams.put("ticket_price_each",ticket_price_each);` sending null value. That's why app was crashed.**

Comment: can you please share the log of

 Log.d(TAG, "size = " + values.size() + " j = " + j + " key= " + key + " & " +    "value=" + value);

Comment: `08-25 11:30:02.243 16386-16386/com.shohoz.launch.cabin D/PostUrlBuilder: size = 1 j = 0 key= ticket_name & value=D205


08-25 11:30:02.243 16386-16386/com.shohoz.launch.cabin D/PostUrlBuilder: size = 1 j = 0 key= ticket_id & value=null`